# Удаление определенных цифр из числа используя только циклы C++

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит любое целое число. Необходимо из этого целого числа удалить все цифры 3 и 6 и вывести обратно на экран.
Мне нужно выполнить это, используя самые основы языка, то есть с помощью циклов

Comment: Можно перевести число в строку и удалить цифры как символы после чего вывести - буквально 3 строчки кода

Comment: Кстати, у вас не определено, что выводить, скажем, для 36... Что за число получается, если в 36 вычеркнуть и 3, и 6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
int main() {
int n;
cin >> n;
//Пропустим первые цифры 3 и 6
while (n > 0 && (n % 10 == 3 || n % 10 == 6))
    n /= 10;
//Первая цифра не 3 и не 6
int without36 = n % 10;
int i = 10;
while (n > 0) {
    //Делим на 10, чтобы перейти к следующей цифре
    n /= 10;
    if (n % 10 != 3 && n % 10 != 6) {
        //Вставляем цифру в начало числа
        without36 += (n % 10) * i;
        i *= 10;
    }
}

cout << without36 << endl;
}
```

Например есть число `132`, тогда после 1 цикла у нас так и останется число `132`, и в переменную `without36` мы запишем цифру `2`. Войдя во второй цикл мы сразу пропустим `2` и получим `13`. И переходим на следующую итерацию т.к. последняя цифра 3. Далее остается `1` и это не `3` и не `6` значит к `without36` добавим `1*i = 10` получив `without36 = 12`.

Я думаю можно проще и элегантней написать алгоритм, но...

**ДОПОЛНЕНО:**

Вот код по красивше) от @Harry:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int without36 = 0;
int i = 1;
while (n) {
    if (n % 10 != 3 && n % 10 != 6) {
        without36 += (n % 10) * i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    n /= 10;
}

cout << without36 << endl;
```

Comment: А зачем отдельный цикл для начальных 3 и 6, например? Почему не просто - http://vpaste.net/eCJER ?

Comment: @Harry я же говорю можно было и лучше, но ...

Answer (score 4):

А зачем циклы? :) Так сойдет?

```
void del36(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n) {
        del36(n / 10);
        if (n%10 != 3 && n % 10 != 6) cout << n%10;
    }
}
```

Ну, чистый введенный 0 обработайте отдельно...